# Simplificar el llamado a funcion de JavaScript para Smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, html, vscode

necesito alguna manera de simplificar esta funcion.

```
$("#btnMain").click(function() {
 var target = $(this.hash);
 iScroll(target);
})

function iScroll(e) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: e.offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
```

Para que de manera simplificada pueda llamarla desde varios objetos del DOM
Ej:

```
$("#btnMain").click(iScroll(e.target))
$("#btnSecondary").click(iScroll(e.target))
$("#btnComment").click(iScroll(e.target))
```

El ejemplo da este error: *ReferenceError: e is not defined*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una variable para guardar la función del scroll, combinada con el código del click callback:

```
var iScroll = function (evento) {
  var target = evento.target;
  var e = $(target.hash);
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: e.offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
```

LLámala así:

```
$("#btnMain").click(iScroll);
```